# Differential equation with constant term to state space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

Let's assume the following set of differential equations describes some biological system:

$$\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1&=u-\alpha x_1\\
\dot{x}_2&=\beta (1 - x_1)-\gamma x_3\\
\dot{x}_3&=\delta(x_2-x_3)\\
y &= x_2
\end{align}$$

where I defined $x_2$ to be the output, and $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are constants.

How can I now transform this system into state-space representation? I.e.

$$\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\dot{x}} &= \boldsymbol{Ax}+\boldsymbol{b}u\\
y  &= \boldsymbol{c}^T\boldsymbol{x} + du
\end{align}$$

I don't know what to do with the constant term in the equation for $x_2$.

Thanks a lot!

**Update:**

As I recently learned,a standard way to do this is to shift the state variables by their equilibrium $\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}$. Thus,

$$
\bar{x}_1=\frac{\bar{u}}{\alpha},\quad\bar{x}_2=\bar{x}_3=\frac{(\alpha-\bar{u})\beta}{\alpha\gamma}
$$

with the new variables $\boldsymbol{z}=\boldsymbol{x}-\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}$ and $v=u-\bar{u}$, we end up with

$$
\boldsymbol{\dot{z}} = \begin{bmatrix}-\alpha & 0 & 0\\-\beta & 0 &-\gamma\\0&\delta&-\delta\end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{z}+\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}v\\
$$
This raises a couple of new questions, though. How do I handle the output $y$ which would certainly not fit into the state-space representation after that transformation since it would read $y_\text{new}=z_2+\bar{x}_2$. Furthermore, did I treat the input $u$ in the correct manner or would such a transformation be carried out on the unforced system, i.e. with $u=0$?

Comment: You could introduce a constant component $\dot x_0=0$ with initial value $1$. Then your second equation reads as $\dot x_1=cx_0-cx_1-x_2$.

Comment: You can also define $x_0=1-x_1$ and thus $x_0'=cx_0-x_2$ and $x_2'=-x_0-x_2+(1+u)$.

Comment: Thanks you two. @player100 if I then furthermore define $v=u+1$ I can get where I want. But, for my actual system that transformation does not work. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: $$x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\1\end{pmatrix}\quad A=\begin{pmatrix}-\alpha&0&0&0\\-\beta&0&-\gamma&\beta\\0&\delta&-\delta&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\quad b=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\quad c=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\quad d=0$$

Comment: You can define input vector $v$ more broadly to include $u$ and constant inputs, like $\beta$.

Comment: Alternatively, I could just define another input and go from a SISO to a MISO system which would result in:
$\boldsymbol{A}=\begin{pmatrix}-\alpha & 0 & 0\\-\beta & 0 & -\gamma\\0 & \delta & -\delta\end{pmatrix}\quad \boldsymbol{b}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & \beta\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ while $x=x$ and $c=c$.